# How to use JSON encoder when serializing a generated Avro class?

Tags: java, json, serialization, avro

I am using the following code to serialize the generated class.

```
GeneratedClass o;

DataFileWriter reflectWriter = new DataFileWriter<>(new ReflectDatumWriter(..));

reflectWriter.append(o);
```

There is no way for me to specify an Encoder to be used in ReflectDatumWriter:

```
writeBytes(Object datum, Encoder out)
```

https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.2/api/java/org/apache/avro/reflect/ReflectDatumWriter.html

Comment: How is your class generated? Can you use the Avro maven plugin instead?

Comment: Yes, I can use Avro maven plugin. No difference whether I use what to generate the class, no?

Comment: I've not had much experience with the ReflectDatumWriter since I don't use very complex types in my Avro, and the AVDL specification works for me.... Unless you're talking about the constructor here, none of the parent classes of ReflectData use an Encoder as a parameter either. It's not really clear what output you're expecting